# Double negation using 2 verbs

Tags: multiple-negation

I am studying English for quite awhile and always have heard about double negation

Is this correct

> I will not regret not marrying you

Or is considered a double negative

Comment: Well, what's the sentence supposed to mean? What do the things you've heard about double-negation tell you about the validity of your sentence? (i.e., do you think it's correct? why or why not?)

Answer (score 1):

The sentence:

> I will not regret not marrying you.

is perfectly fine. There's no double negative. "Not marrying you" is what you will not regret, and there's really no better way to express that (I can't think of a word that means "not marrying you").

Answer (score 0):

It is a *kind* of double negative, but a necessary one.

With a true double negative (which is usually considered to be an error) the two negatives cancel each other out and convey the opposite message than perhaps intended. In this case, the statement makes sense and it seems like the speaker knows exactly what they mean to say.

Evidently the speaker did not marry the person they are speaking to. And they are saying they do not regret that decision. Arguably, they could remove both negatives and convey a similar sentiment:

> I would regret marrying you.

However, this is not exactly the same thing. This would be a *hypothetical* statement about how they *would* feel if they did marry, whereas the original shows how they *do* feel about the decision *not* to.